# Calculate subnet in Solaris shell

Tags: shell, awk, netmask

I need to calculate the subnet, having a IP address and net mask in a Solaris machine shell (bash, but could be other).

Some examples:

```
IP=192.168.100.6, MASK=255.255.255.0 => SUBNET=192.168.100.0
IP=11.95.189.33, MASK=255.255.0.0 => SUBNET=11.95.0.0
IP=66.25.144.216, MASK=255.255.255.192 => SUBNET=66.25.144.192
```

I have two ways to calculate this:

```
SUBNET=$((`echo $IP | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "." } ; {print $1}'`&`echo $MASK | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "." } ; {print $1}'`)).\
$((`echo $IP | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "." } ; {print $2}'`&`echo $MASK | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "." } ; {print $2}'`)).\
$((`echo $IP | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "." } ; {print $3}'`&`echo $MASK | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "." } ; {print $3}'`)).\
$((`echo $IP | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "." } ; {print $4}'`&`echo $MASK | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "." } ; {print $4}'`))
```

and

```
l="${IP%.*}";r="${IP#*.}";n="${MASK%.*}";m="${MASK#*.}"
subnet=$((${IP%%.*}&${NM%%.*})).$((${r%%.*}&${m%%.*})).$((${l##*.}&${n##*.})).$((${IP##*.}&${NM##*.}))
```

But I think both of them are a little "dirty". I would like a "cleaner" way to calculate the subnet, easy to understand by other people in my project.

I prefer not to use *perl* or *python*, but could be considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you store your ip and mask into two shell variables: `$ip` and `$mask`:

```
 awk -vip="$ip" -vmask="$mask" 'BEGIN{
split(ip,a, "."); 
split(mask,b,".");
for(i=1;i<=4;i++)a[i]=b[i]==255?a[i]:b[i]; 
printf"SUBNET=";for(i=1;i<=3;i++)printf a[i]".";printf a[4]}'
```

will give you result in format: `SUBNET=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

take one example:

```
kent$  ip="192.168.100.6"                                                                                                                                                   

kent$  mask="255.255.255.192"                                                                                                                                               

kent$  awk -vip="$ip" -vmask="$mask" 'BEGIN{split(ip,a, "."); split(mask,b,".");for(i=1;i<=4;i++)a[i]=b[i]==255?a[i]:b[i]; printf"SUBNET=";for(i=1;i<=3;i++)printf a[i]".";printf a[4]}'
SUBNET=192.168.100.192
```

Comment: this does only work if the ip is in first subnet in major network. Eg. it doesn't work for ip="10.0.0.99" vmask="255.255.255.196"

Comment: @Kveri what result are you expecting?

Comment: sorry, I meant vip="10.0.0.99" and vmask="255.255.255.192". The result given by your code is SUBNET=10.0.0.192. The correct result is 10.0.0.64

Comment: @Kveri you can downvote the answer, fine. but OP wrote this in question: `IP=66.25.144.216, MASK=255.255.255.192 => SUBNET=66.25.144.192` He also gave his codes(algorithm). I just gave my answer from my understanding of the question and his codes. Read the question please.

Comment: are you trying to write algorithm to solve one particular problem with one particular set of parameters? What kind of algorithm is that if it can only return the correct result for some parameters, but not for others. The defined set of input values is well known and your algorithm doesn't return the correct result for all of them, so the algorithm is not correct. I'm not okay with half solutions. If I take it your way then the best "algorithm" for his exact question is just "return '66.25.144.192'", isn't it?

Comment: @Kveri IMO, OP defines if is a solution "correct".  input `1+1`, I want to get `100`, then `100` is correct.

Comment: and what? It is correct for him so he marks it as correct. It is not okay for me, I downvote it. Are you really arguing? This solution is useful only for him and only because he doesn't read these comments. If he used this code in any application that application would malfunction. If answered correctly, this answer could've been used by many, not just one.

Comment: why not just upvote the solution below? That is the correct one.

Comment: @Kveri I am not unhappy for your downvote, and I said, it is "fine". The SO site is for solving specific questions, if questions are helpful for others, good. if not, fine too. If you think you have better idea, post your answer. and I am not arguing with you.

Answer (score 1):

My solution does what is actually needed to be done. The Ip and mask are 'and'-ed together. This is what I have used.

assuming, here $ip and $mask are defined shell variables.

```
awk -vip="$ip" -vmask="$mask" 'BEGIN{
  sub("addr:","",ip);
  sub("Mask:","",mask);
  split(ip,a,".");
  split(mask,b,".");
  for(i=1;i<=4;i++)
    s[i]=and(a[i],b[i]);
  subnet=s[1]"."s[2]"."s[3]"."s[4]; 
  print subnet;
}'
```

compressed:

```
awk -vip="$ip" -vmask="$mask" 'BEGIN{sub("addr:","",ip);sub("Mask:","",mask);split(ip,a,".");split(mask,b,".");for(i=1;i<=4;i++)s[i]=and(a[i],b[i]);subnet=s[1]"."s[2]"."s[3]"."s[4];print subnet;}'
```

Works similar to the example given by kent.

Example:

```
[rahul]$ ip=172.16.232.159
[rahul]$ mask=255.255.254.0
[rahul]$ awk -vip="$ip" -vmask="$mask" 'BEGIN{sub("addr:","",ip);sub("Mask:","",mask);split(ip,a,".");split(mask,b,".");for(i=1;i<=4;i++)s[i]=and(a[i],b[i]);subnet=s[1]"."s[2]"."s[3]"."s[4];print subnet;}'
172.16.232.0
```

Comment: I like this one, but seems you are using [gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Bitwise-Functions.html)  
I have 3 times the error "function and never defined"

Comment: Nice code. Do you have a suggestion for an AWK function for this notation: 192.168.23.193/24?